# How to use custom fonts in JFreeChart diagrams?

Tags: fonts, jfreechart, custom-font

How can I use custom fonts in JFreeChart diagrams? More details: I have the Time Series Chart and font file *geogtqrg.ttf*. So I need to assign this font to chart?

Thanks for reply!

It seems to be, that this task can be solved by `setLabelFont`, however how to define the font-file in this method correctly?

Comment: Have you looked at using `org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme `?

Comment: No, I will if you think that it worth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/StandardChartTheme.html) offers some consistency in using font's. Just [create](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html#bundling-physical-fonts-with-your-application) your `Font`, specify the desired font(s) in a `ChartTheme`, and ask `ChartFactory` to apply the new theme for you when creating new charts. Do something like this (untested) fragment:

```java
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("geogtqrg.ttf"));
StandardChartTheme chartTheme = new StandardChartTheme("GeoTheme");
chartTheme.setExtraLargeFont(font.deriveFont(24f));
chartTheme.setLargeFont(font.deriveFont(16f));
chartTheme.setRegularFont(font.deriveFont(12f));
chartTheme.setSmallFont(font.deriveFont(10f));
ChartFactory.setChartTheme(chartTheme);
```